# What is this nose projection on the Tupolev Tu-95?

Tags: feature-identification

The Tupolev Tu-95 has this long and quite substantial appearing projection from it's nose just under the cockpit windscreen:

[image: Tupolev Tu-95]

What is this? I initially though this might be a cannon but being a heavy bomber, that makes little sense as it would be quite difficult to aim effectively.

Comment: I always assumed it is an air-to-air refuelling probe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That boom is the **refueling probe** used for in-air refueling:

[image: Tu-95RT]

<sup>(image source: [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.at/pin/the-bear--348958671107437638/))</sup>

You can see it in action in this photo, where an Il-76 is refueling a Tu-95:

[image: Tu-95 getting a refuel from a Il-76]

<sup>(image source: [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MilitaryPorn/comments/f5j4cv/tu95_getting_a_refuel_from_a_il76/))</sup>